# jQuery AJAX GET to a Servlet doesn't show the JSP page - instead returns with HTML code

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I know I am doing something stupid and wrong but I can't figure it out. Please help.

I am using Apache Tomcat Servlet 7 with JQuery.

On my web page, when I click on a button, a Jquery GET call is made to my servlet URL. The servlet, after receiving the data (in JSON format), processes the data and creates some result parameters. Then the servlet passes those parameters to a JSP file to load the JSP page. So in summary, when the user clicks on a button, processing happens on the servlet and the result JSP page is loaded.

The problem is, when I make a Jquery GET call from the button, no result page is loaded. Instead when I do console.log(request), I see the entire html content of the rendered JSP page.

Here's my code on the web application when the button is clicked:

```
var request;
if (request) {
   request.abort();
}
request = $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url:'http://<MyServerAddress>:8080/<App>/<Servlet>',
     data: {
        'queryType' : 'clickButton',
        'data' : JSON.stringify(buttonPageInfo)
         },
}); 
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response)); 
        // shows the entire html content of the processed JSP page that I want to load
     });
```

Here's the code on the server side:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   processData(request, response);
}

protected void processData(request, response) {
 /* Do some processing on the data and come up with results */
 RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/myJSPPage.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response); 
}
```

Right after `rd.forward(request, response)`, I expect my web page forward to myJSPPage.jsp to show the result, but nothing happens. Instead `console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response));` shows the entire HTML content of the JSP page with the results I am expecting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe the problem is that you must have some placeholder in your DOM to update with the HTML you're getting from your request. Usually, that's what AJAX is for. To retrieve small portions of data to update in your DOM.

Comment: Do you want to show a new page after the user hits the button? If yes you don't need ajax, just call `windows.open()`.

Comment: @BetaRide you are right. With fresh pair of eyes and relaxed mind, I realized that I don't need to make an AJAX call. Just a simple API call to my web application (http://myserver:8080/servlet?data=var1&data=var2) does the trick.

Comment: So I added the comment as an answer :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `windows.open()` if you want to do a normal page call. No need to use ajax for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting HTML because you are forwarding to a JSP.

Just remove the RequestDispatcher stuff and make sure that you have flushed the response data.